# How to access TextBox in MenuFlyout from VB / C# code

Tags: c#, vb.net, xaml

I need help on accessing eg. the TextBox from code. I use VB but C# example is welcome too.
If I try to access the TextBox by typing txtSettingsCity VB doesn't recognize the TextBox.

I am very grateful for any. Thank you in advance.

```
            <Button x:Name="btnSettings" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE115;" Foreground="{StaticResource NuhmeTextColor}" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" Margin="4,0,0,4">
            <Button.Flyout>
                <MenuFlyout x:Name="mfSettings">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="mfiSettings">
                        <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
                                <StackPanel Margin="4,10,4,0" Orientation="Vertical" Width="130">
                                    <TextBox x:Name="txtSettingsCity" Header="Din placering" PlaceholderText="Ribe, Danmark" Width="130" Margin="0,0,0,10" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Indtast din placering eller klik søg"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="btnFindLocation" Content="Søg" Margin="80,0,0,10" Click="btnFindLocation_Click"/>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make use of the `VisualTreeHelprer` , here's a quick code sample;

```
  Public Shared Function FindParent(Of T As DependencyObject)(ByVal child As DependencyObject) As T
    Dim parentObject As DependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child)
    If parentObject Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    Dim parent As T = TryCast(parentObject, T)
    If parent IsNot Nothing Then Return parent Else Return FindParent(Of T)(parentObject)
End Function
```

A usage of the function :

```
  Dim parent As ControlTypeHere= FindParent(Of ControlTypeHere)(Me)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. However, I can not make it work. I receive an error "NullReferenceException"

Comment: which line throws the exception ?

Comment: I use TextBox where you typed ControlTypeHere. I tried with your function in a class and also in a module. Same result. It is not your function that throws an exception, but my approach to read the result.        
Debug.WriteLine(parent.Name) throws an exception

Comment: No.....Lolz...This code is to find a parent for a child control...Like, for example , you have a page and you display it in a frame...Then you can use my method to find the parent of the page which is a frame...Anyways, clarify your situation , i'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You CAN loop through VisualTreeHelper.GetParent to first get the parent MenuFlyoutItem and then recursively use VisualTreeHelper.GetChild to return the TextBox.

HOWEVER, I highly recommend exploring an MVVM approach and binding the Button.Command to an ICommand and passing the TextBox binding as the Button.CommandParameter.

**Quick and Dirty Example**

```
private void btnFindLocation_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var target = sender as DependencyObject;

    while (target != null)
    {
        target = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(target);

        if (target is MenuFlyoutItem menuFlyoutItem)
        {
            if (GetChild<TextBox>(menuFlyoutItem) is TextBox textBox)
            {
                // Access the TextBox here
                Debug.WriteLine(textBox.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}

private TFrameworkElement GetChild<TFrameworkElement>(FrameworkElement parent) where TFrameworkElement : FrameworkElement
{
    var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

    for (var index = 0; index < count; ++index)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, index) as FrameworkElement;

        if (child is TFrameworkElement frameworkElement)
        {
            return frameworkElement;
        }
        else
        {
            if (GetChild<TFrameworkElement>(child) is TFrameworkElement grandChild)
            {
                return grandChild;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer rather a few words of suggestion .... please add these sort of suggestions in the comment